# How to override a key of an object in an array of objects returned from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, express

I can't seem to override a key on objects in an array returned from a mongodb query...

I have this array of objects, and I just want to override a key, with an edited value.

Basically what I want to do is that I have a key like `obj.location.address` which may have a value like `wall street 34`

I want to add a regex to the string so that it becomes `wall street`

I try to map over the array of objs and try to override the key with the value of the result of the value passed through a regex...

But it doesn't work... My new array instead of being an array of objects, becomes just an array of strings with the values of `obj.location.address` which are just strings of addresses like `wall street 34`, which is super strange.

My code:

```
exports.mapUsers = async (req, res) => {
  const coordinates = [req.query.lng, req.query.lat].map(parseFloat);
  const q = {
    location: {
      $near: {
        $geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates
        },
        $maxDistance: 10000 // 10km
      }
    }
  };

  const receivedUsers = await User.find(q).select('name location musicLinks genres photo slug skills').limit(10);

  const users = receivedUsers.map( obj => obj.location.address = obj.location.address.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ", "))
  console.log(users)
  res.json(users)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mapping like this. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
const users = receivedUsers.map(user => {
  user.location.address = user.location.address.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ", ");
  return user;
});
```